# How to set the USER_AGENT for gslib when using gsutil CLI 4.51?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

What I am trying to do: copy contents of a folder to a bucket. I have successfully done this in earlier versions of gsutil. Not sure if its the python version OR the gsutil version that caused this to break now. Any insights?

Command:  `gsutil -m cp -r . gs://target-bucket-url`
Running: MacOS 10.15.5

Got the following error when trying the above command:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 243, in serve_client
    request = recv()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 251, in recv
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
  File "/Users/user-x/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/commands/cp.py", line 30, in <module>
    from gslib.command import Command
  File "/Users/user-x/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/command.py", line 50, in <module>
    from gslib.cloud_api_delegator import CloudApiDelegator
  File "/Users/user-x/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/cloud_api_delegator.py", line 26, in <module>
    from gslib.cs_api_map import ApiMapConstants
  File "/Users/user-x/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/cs_api_map.py", line 23, in <module>
    from gslib.gcs_json_api import GcsJsonApi
  File "/Users/user-x/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/gcs_json_api.py", line 72, in <module>
    from gslib.third_party.storage_apitools import storage_v1_client as apitools_client
  File "/Users/user-x/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/third_party/storage_apitools/storage_v1_client.py", line 26, in <module>
    class StorageV1(base_api.BaseApiClient):
  File "/Users/user-x/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/third_party/storage_apitools/storage_v1_client.py", line 38, in StorageV1
    _USER_AGENT += gslib.USER_AGENT
AttributeError: module 'gslib' has no attribute 'USER_AGENT'
```

gsutil version: 4.51
python version: 3.8

Comment: I had the same problem with same OS version, gsutil version and python 3.8, to unblock my project I tried with python 3.7 and it worked with no error, so if it's urgent maybe you can try with python < 3.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue and the Google team is taking a look at it at this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/160074681), I recommend you to go there and add more information if possible: AttributeError: module 'gslib' has no attribute 'USER_AGENT'

Comment: thanks for the issue tracker reference. looks like google team might have released a fix for this, as captured here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/1052.  As referred in one of the comments there, the issue comes up when using the '-m' flag.

Answer (score 0):

Setting python version to python 3.7 as suggested at the [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/160074681) tracker worked for me. Below is the working configuration.

```
$ cat ~/.bash_profile
alias python='python3.7'
.....

$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: I think this is just a workaround not an answer yet, the problem persists with 3.8 version so as I suggested in the issue tracker if it's urgent change the python version, we should wait for a fix from google cloud team.

Comment: agree @neosergio. My attempt was meant to demonstrate  the workaround.

Comment: thanks for this workaround. I did get around my blocking issue at that time. But good to know it didnt break with python3.7.